# Создание Java-ярлыка в рабочем окружении KDE. Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, kubuntu

Хочу создать ярлык Java-приложения у себя на рабочем столе (и вообще чтобы в списке приложений было. Файл я создал в директории usr/share/applications с расширением .desktop, все прописал, но почему-то выскакивает ошибка "KDE Init не может запустить файл.jar"

```
`[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mlauncher
Comment=Лаунчер для игры в майнкрафт
Exec=/home/nazar/mlauncher/mlauncher.jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=mlauncher_icon.png
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
`
```

Comment: что вы написали после `exec=`, то и пытается компьютер выполнить. вы ж наверняка как-то по-другому запускаете. типа `java путь.к.файлу`. так и напишите.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно не просто указать путь к файлу, а выполнить команду:

```
java -jar /path/to/jar
```